# In Minecraft, what hardware component(s) govern textures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

I'm getting an unplayable FPS in minecraft. Looking at the debug information (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), it says that Tick takes much of (whatever it's measuring), of which the dominant thing is "textures".

I'm wondering what hardware component limits that, and how I would measure/diagnose that component. I assume it's either the CPU or the GPU. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any kind of texture pack? High-res texture packs take up significantly more VRAM than the default textures.
What GPU are you running MineCraft on?

Comment: Yes I'm using texture packs. System has 24 gigs of ram and I've allocated 12 (I think) to java.

GPU is a Radeon R9 200 series.

Comment: Ok, that's enough space for a hi-res texture pack I think, but those textures have to be loaded into your Graphics card's VRAM as well. I'm assuming that with your 24GB RAM you also have a descent GPU with at least 2GB VRAM.

Comment: Do you observe any difference in performance after standing in the same location for a while vs. moving around or is the FPS equally low all the time?

Comment: The easy diagnosis is to disable the texture pack and measure your FPS change. If it's significant, the texture pack is likely to blame. Certain texture packs are created extremely poorly (ie using huge images -- high DPS for example) instead of more appropriately sized resolutions) and can easily overwhelm your texture renderer. The amount of system RAM is important, but it's not used as efficiently as you'd think during the rendering process. That's why video cards have their own RAM, because it's faster than using that of the system in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

To a degree both are involved,
 the CPU is responsible for keeping track of what polygons should be rendered where, and with what texture. It also directs the GPU so that it may perform its part of the rendering

The GPU is responsible for rendering those polygons on screen and filling them with the textures

Comment: That answer is useful, thanks. Because I don't know enough to decide if it's "correct", I'm not yet marking it as accepted.

Comment: A quick thing to look at it to see if any of the cores on your processor are at 100% utilization, Minecraft's rendering engine only single-threaded, if one of its threads has 100% utilization of a core you're probably CPU bound otherwise it's probably GPU.